# Design issue when using Getter and Setter?

Tags: c#, getter-setter

I have a problem I am unable to solve elegantly without over-polluting my getter and setter.
Context:
I have a Parameter class that has a property Value (that uses a getter and a setter). Anybody can access and modify that value.
This value is say a floating point value, but it must also be converted back and forth into fixed point. In other words, when updating the floating point value, we need to make sure that its fixed point equivalent gets updated (but that is happening in the setter).
Now considering the fixed point values are representing a memory space, they can also get modified directly without using the parameter class. This means that the getter also needs to be complicated and retrieve the fixed point value (in case it has changed), apply some transform and return it as a floating point number.

Here is what the setter and getter currently look like:

```
private TType _value;

public TType Value
{
    get
    {
       // Check for changes
       if (ValueUnchanged)   // Simplified for readability
           return _value;

       // Code simplified for clarity - There are many more lines and checks in this routine
       _value = ApplyAppropriateTransform(GetFixedPointValue(X));   

        return _value;
    }
    set
    {
        // Code simplified for clarity - There are many more lines and checks in this routine

        // Should not be able to set _value to null
        if (value == null)
            return;    
  
        if (_value.Equals(value))
            return;

        // Validate Value range and backing up GUI value
        _value = CheckRange(value);

        X = ApplyAppropriateReverseTransform(_value);

        // Set Fixed point value in cache memory, to be sent to EEPROM outside this setter
        SetFixedPointValue(X);
    }
}
```

Is this approach reasonable? If not, what would be the right way to do this?

Comment: What else do you suggest you do?  As long as your setter logic is not dependant on another properties value, I guess this is acceptable.

Comment: @monstertjie_za, thanks. That is why I am asking, I am not sure it is acceptable as the ApplyAppropriateTransform and ApplyAppropriateReverseTransform could add up to over 50 lines of code. I just can't think of a better approach though :-)

Comment: I do not like getters/setters containing logic. In know that in the end getters/setters are also just methods. But a getter/setter should be easier to read than a method. Just my opinion. And why can the underlaying value be changed outside of the setter? Sounds strange. Why try to encapsulate something which isn't encapsulated?

Comment: @user743414, that is because the parameter class is the interface. A user can modify this value via eg. a GUI, but these values end up in memory (EEPROM) as a fixed point number. Note that the setter/getter are not responsible for the EEPROM access directly, don't worry ;-).

Comment: I guess it's not wrong to do it this way. If this would be a class of a SDK or something. I would expect to call a method to get some results from memory and not a property. But I also think it depends on what you like or not. :)

Comment: @user743414, correct those values are only cached here. No direct access with the EEPROM is done here.

Comment: What is this mysterious `X`?

Comment: I would suggest that you have a simple property with a backing field for the raw number. Then a separate read only property that converts that value into the fixed point that you are after.

Answer (score 0):

Would this do what you're after?

```
public class NumericClass
{
    private float _rawValue =0;
    private int _numPlaces=1;
    public float RawValue{
        get=>_rawValue;
        set=> _rawValue = value;
    }
    public decimal FixedPoint{
        get=> decimal.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(_rawValue), _numPlaces);
        set => _rawValue = Convert.ToSingle(value);
    }
    public int NumberOfPlaces{
        get=>_numPlaces;
        set=>_numPlaces = value;
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var numeric = new NumericClass();
        numeric.RawValue = 123.4567f;
        Console.WriteLine($"numeric.FixedPoint= {numeric.FixedPoint}");
        numeric.NumberOfPlaces=3;
        Console.WriteLine($"numeric.FixedPoint= {numeric.FixedPoint}");
        
        numeric.FixedPoint = 345.678m;
        Console.WriteLine($"numeric.RawValue = {numeric.RawValue}");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
numeric.FixedPoint= 123.5
numeric.FixedPoint= 123.457
numeric.RawValue = 345.678
```

You could add a trigger to run a command/function that uses `FixedPoint` elsewhere.

If the change between types is purely for UI then I would place the conversion in the UI related code and just use the format required by the application logic elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks. There can be many types of UIs in our system, so I'd rather not duplicate the logic.
In your example, you are assuming the NumericClass owns the fixed Point equivalent, but in my case, it has to be written to a cache (which my Parameter class refers to and does not owns nor instantiates).